# Why I'm using "request.getPrincipal()" to get the authenticated user?

Tags: java, security, authentication, request, single-sign-on

This might be some "rookie" question, but I can't find a direct answer during my research.

Working with a JAVA Web project (that makes use of SSO), there are some libraries getting the logged user the following way: "request.getUserPrincipal();".

It was alarming to me, receiving this data on the request, since that could be imposed (my first assumption is that the request comes from the webclient/browser).

But checking the running application, I don't see a single place where that data travels in the request (more than the log in page itself, that of course sends username and password).

So, I'm assuming that the server is augmenting the request and putting the user information that is actually stored in the session (which would be secure) but I can't find any clear documentation that supports my theory.

So, could anybody explain or point me to some good and straight explanation?

Thanks! Regards.

Answer (score 2):

JavaDoc of `HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()` says:

> Returns a java.security.Principal object containing the name of the current authenticated user. If the user has not been authenticated, the method returns null.

You are right, it does not directly states where this information comes from. Actually there might be different sources where the authentication and corresponding `Principal` object are coming from.

Documentation defines a contract that in case of present authentication, object is returned and `null` if no authentication present.

Most often this works in combination with the session but it is easily possible to have an SSO implementation which does not use `HttpSession` but is based e.g. on JWT Token being present in each HTTP request.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Documentation could be a little bit frustrating. If it's working with the session, I'm trying to list all session variables to check what's going on there. If it's a JWT token, I assume that it's randomly generated and hard/impossible to fake. In that case, JWT token should have all the data association on the server side someplace. Do you know where? Thanks again.

Comment: It really depends on the specific container and setup. For example tomcat, caches previously-authenticated Principle object inside of an internal session - your application does not see the objects stored there.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I researched, browsed code, and found an answer. Long story short: I'm using Tomcat. Indeed, Tomcat stores the Principal information on the session, and during a single sign on driven request, it augment the request information but always on server side. I'll make some time to document it somehow, and post a new answer here.